# repeating rows in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
    <table style='border: 1px solid black' id="tableContainer">
        <tr style='border: 1px solid black'>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>wiadomość</th>
            <th>godzina</th>
            <th>nazwa użytkownika</th>
        </tr>
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                <tr style='border: 1px solid black' id="post_{{ post.id }}">
                    <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ post.text }}</td>
                    <td>{{ post.time|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ post.getUserId().getUsername() }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% else %}
                {% if post.id != posts[loop.index - 2].id %}
                    <tr style='border: 1px solid black' id="post_{{ post.id }}">
                        <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ post.text }}</td>
                        <td>{{ post.time|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ post.getUserId().getUsername() }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <form method="post" action="{{ path('logout') }}">
        <input type="submit" value="wyloguj">
    </form>
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var lastPostId = $("#tableContainer tr:last").attr("id").split("_")[1];
        var lastPostText = $("#tableContainer tr:last td:nth-child(2)").text();

        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ path('showTable') }}",
                type: 'GET',
                data: { lastPostId: lastPostId },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var newPostText = $(data).find("td:nth-child(2)").text(); 
                        if($(data) != $("#tableContainer tr:last")) { 
                            $('#tableContainer').append(data);
                            lastPostId = $("#tableContainer tr:last").attr("id").split("_")[1];
                            lastPostText = newPostText; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>

</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Every two seconds my page searches for new posts - and if there are any, my script will add new row(s) to my table. But I have error because if the script didn't find a new row in database, the script will add the same row(s) as before.

Also, when another user send two messages in a row, Javascript will add those two rows every two second.

Can someone help? I can confirm that in the database itself everything works.

Comment: The logic should be in the server side really, to only return posts later than the lastPostId which you send in the ajax request

Comment: I corrected your spelling, grammer and language. If it all possible, please pay more attention when writing a question. It wasn't easy working out what you are trying to say.

Comment: You seem to be using JQuery and some kind of templating language. If you do, please specify those in your question and tags. The tags are really important.